# What is the agama being followed by the Sri Nataraja temple in Chidambaram and why is it different from other Shiva temples?

Tags: temple, agamas

Shaiva agamas form the basis of worship in temples dedicated to Lord Shiva. However, it seems like the Sri Nataraja temple in the town of Chidambaram, Tamilnadu is not built and/or not follows the standard shaiva agamas. [This](http://www.templenet.com/Tamilnadu/chidchid.html) page also mentions the same.

> The Shiva Agama system of temple rituals followed in almost all of the
>   Saivite temples in Tamilnadu, is not followed at Chidambaram. It is a
>   unique worship protocol said to have been prescribed by Patanjali that
>   is followed at this temple.

It is also well known that the temple is not run by the traditional Shivacharyas but by Dikshitars, who are termed as vaidika brahmins [here](http://www.chidambaramnataraja.org/deekshithar.html).

Both sites mention that the temple in Chidambaram follows rules laid down by Patanjali but give no more details, which then brings us to the question:

What agama is being followed in Chidambaram temple? Do we have evidence of the text being put forth by Patanjali? What is the reason, historical or/and scriptural, this temple alone does not follow the Shaiva agamas?

Comment: Google *Thevaaram*

Comment: I think there's a story Patanjali came to Chidambaram for witnessing Cosmic dance, but was the rules laid down by Patanjali>?

Comment: @AkshayS That's what I am asking about. :D

Comment: That temple has yogic connection if we see = it has 9 entry points to temple, with 21600 feet Kalasa... So construction of it gives hints but still let me search for proper source!

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri Thevaaram is not an agama. They might make references to agamas, but the point is none of the Shaiva agamas is applied in Chidambaram. So can you help me by being specific on what I should be looking for when I google it?

Comment: @AkshayS haha... more numbers and patterns. :D. I am also searching, so we will share what we find.That's why we have this site, no?

Comment: So the tenth "volume" of *Thevaaram* is *Thirumandiram* composed by *Thirumular* who was both a *Naayanmaar* and *Siddhar*. He discusses in detail the Agamas, in particular, it contains the relation to Patanjali's Yoga Siddhantam

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri thanks. That turns up a whole new set of search results. It is interesting to note that both Patanjali and Thirumoolar are shown on the doors of the chit sabha. May be that is the link. But still more details are needed to complete the full picture. Will keep looking in to it.

Comment: yw. And when you do figure out the finer details, don't forget to write an answer!

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri Haha... yeah, looks like a couple of my questions will be answered by me alone.

Comment: oh, which is the other question?

Comment: @SudarshanaSuri you can take a look here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/16773/ambi?tab=questions esp the one related to Divya Prabhandham